# Why doesn't the simplest LinearModel converge?

Tags: tensorflow

I had to use `tf.data.Dataset` explicitly to get a `tf.keras.experimental.LinearModel` fitted without weights (i.e. with bias only), but I think I have it set up right:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

batch = 1000
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (
        np.ones(shape=(batch, 0), dtype=float),
        np.ones(shape=(batch,), dtype=float),
    )
)
```

Note that the inputs are empty, because their shape has a zero. Okay, let's try to estimate bias (it should converge to 1.0).

```
lm = tf.keras.experimental.LinearModel(1)
lm.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
)
lm.fit(dataset.batch(batch), epochs=100, verbose=0)
lm.get_weights()
```

```
[array([], shape=(0, 1), dtype=float32), array([1.9999833], dtype=float32)]
```

Huh, that's not so good. Maybe it's just really slow.

```
lm.fit(dataset.batch(batch), epochs=100, verbose=0)
lm.get_weights()
```

```
[array([], shape=(0, 1), dtype=float32), array([5.9999557], dtype=float32)]
```

Wait, it's getting worse? Please help me understand what's going on, and show me how you can poke the model to see it. Thanks!

Comment: In contrast, I've found that using `tf.ones` as input to a `tf.keras.Model` with output given by `tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, use_bias=False)` works just great.